# Angular ng-grid doesn't refreshes when modified from modal

Tags: angularjs

On the page, I have some textboxes and a submit button. Based a values of textboxes and button click, a grid is displayed. The grid has some columns followed by a column which contains delete button. Clicking on delete button opens a modal for confirmation. Clicking Yes on modal deletes the record and closes the modal. Ideally, the grid should refresh and automatically display the refreshed grid. However, it doesnt. So I have to manually click the submit button to get the refreshed grid. Is there something caching going on here? How can I get the refreshed grid without clicking submit?

For simplicity, I am only displaying the important pieces of code

```
$scope.showGrid = function () { // Called on submit button click

        $http.post(postUrl, { type: $scope.selectedType, branchId: $scope.selectedBranch }).success(function (responseData) {

                $scope.gridData = JSON.parse(responseData.d);
        })
    };


// Function to delete a record
    $scope.deleteRecord = function (id) { // takes id of the record to delete

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {
                editId: function () {
                    return id;
                },
                type: function () {
                    return $scope.selectedType;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
            $scope.gridData = '';  // I am clearing the variable just to ensure gridData doesnt have old values
            $scope.showGrid();  // calling the grid function
            toaster.success({ title: "Success", body: "The schedule has been deleted successfully!" });
        });
    };


app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', .... // Modal code to delete the record
```

Comment: can you post the complete code with html? possibly in a fiddle?

Comment: Is it a timing thing? Can you show how you are deleting the record? I've had the issue where closing a modal deletes a record and then the page requeries the data, but the query was too fast and happened 'before' the data had been refreshed. So even though it successfully deleted, getting the data didn't reflect that

Comment: What is $scope.gridData?  is that what you have set to the data field in the options that you pass to your grid?  If so then changing it will cause the grid to change.  e.g.  $scope.myOptions = {data:'gridData'}; and then <div ui-grid="myOptions"...>

Comment: @KevinF So what did you do to get it to work? My delete has nothing but a call to webservice passing the id I wanted to delete.  $scope.yes = function () {

            var postUrl = 'app/scheduler/deleteFormat.asmx/delete';

            $http.post(postUrl, { type: type, id: editId }).success(function (responseData) {

            });

            $modalInstance.close();

        };

Comment: To test if it is an issue you can wrap your $http.post in a timeout of like 10 seconds or something. You can also console.log the result of the http post to make sure it is getting updated data, if it is then its an issue with the view updating

Comment: @KevinF   It seems it is conflicting with toaster. So if I comment the toaster successful line, it does automatic refresh. There is nothing in console indicating any error. Nor do I have knowledge to mess with it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try returning the promise from your showGrid function and calling the toaster after that resolves in case they are somehow conflicting

```
$scope.showGrid = function () { // Called on submit button click
    return $http.post(postUrl, { type: $scope.selectedType, branchId: $scope.selectedBranch }).success(function (responseData) {
        $scope.gridData = JSON.parse(responseData.d);
    })
};

// Function to delete a record
    $scope.deleteRecord = function (id) { // takes id of the record to delete

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {
                editId: function () {
                    return id;
                },
                type: function () {
                    return $scope.selectedType;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
            $scope.gridData = '';  // I am clearing the variable just to ensure gridData doesnt have old values
            $scope.showGrid().then(function(){ // calling the grid function
                toaster.success({ title: "Success", body: "The schedule has been deleted successfully!" });
            });  

        });
    };
```